# Save WebBrowser Control Content to HTML

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser Control and have called the Navigate(url) function of it for a given file. Then I have manipulated the DOM tree by giving new Id's to some of the tags.

Now I want to save the result in an HTML file. I have tried to use the webBrowser.DocumentStream, but it seems that this stream won't change after manipulating the DOM tree.

Please keep in mind that the encoding in WebBrowser.Document.Encoding must be used to encode the result.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like this:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, browser.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml, Encoding.GetEncoding(browser.Document.Encoding));
```

Comment: This probably only writes the body of the document. I want the header too, which contains stylesheets and scripts.

Comment: That's why I wrote `Body.Parent`.

Comment: Note: With this way we will save only HTML body that not contains *DocType* tag ;).