# Save RENDERED webpage with content. C# or maybe some cpecialized tool/plugin

Tags: c#

I want to save multiple webpages with all their content, which is not that hard by itself, and there are multiple tools for this task.

But pages themselves are hard to work with.

They are rendered on client side (by javascript), so just grabbing what lies in html on server does no good.

Some tools can deal with this, they grab rightly processed html, look for pictures URLs inside html and then try to download them.

And here is other problem, images can not be downloaded directly, only as webpage content. And here I am stuck.

I tried to make my own tool for this task in C#, and looks like `webBrowser` + `ShowSaveAsDialog` works fine, but it can not be automated.

Is there any way to render html and save all its content in "silent mode"?

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is the "Save File Dialog" you can save silentently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2976716/1271037

but i suggest you see this article series: [Webscraping with C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1041115/Webscraping-with-Csharp)

Comment: I have not found `SaveDocument` method in `webBrowser`.

[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx)
But thanks for link, will look there.