# How to save-as html file, an embeded browser display?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vb.net

I have upgraded the performance of the VS 2019 WebBrowser control by adding  to the html file, thanks to https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version. As backup I have Geckofx 45 working as well. Based on what I have read neither one can save what is displayed as an html file, which is what I need. Can someone lead me to a solution?

Comment: what langauage are you using javascript or vb Do you have any code?

Comment: Not clear what is your context. Using a WebBrowser class, in the `DocumentCompleted` event: `if ([WebBrowser].ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return; using (var reader = new StreamReader([WebBrowser].DocumentStream)) { string html = reader.ReadToEnd(); }`

Comment: ...and I posted it in C#. The VB.Net version is: `If [WebBrowser].ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete then return Using reader as StreamReader = new StreamReader([WebBrowser].DocumentStream) Dim html as string = reader.ReadToEnd() end using`

Comment: I load data into a table from an outside csv file into my html, css, js file. My embedded browser displays as expected with data in the table. Using your vb.net code it saves everything without the table and data. I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: You can use that code anywhere, when needed. If you `.Write` into the Document with a Javascript, this is done after the page is loaded. So, you can get the document html as text with `Dim html As String = WebBrowser1.DocumentText`, after you have generated a `<table>` with a script.

Comment: I execute the code with a button after the table is loaded and displayed. I changed from DocumentStream to DocumentText and now I get an error: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: What path? Are you trying to save the html to disc? If so, then check the path you've specified. If you're on the Server side, use [Server.MapPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath)

Comment: The is no server involved, I am saving to C:\Users\name\desktop\my.html. I think You identified the problem, the table and data are added after the page is loaded. If I load an html file that is complete (no loading of data into the page) the save to html code works fine. Some how I need to get the loaded file look like a page. I may not be saying this totally correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jimi and the following two posts:https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version.  [Save WebBrowser Control Content to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976701/save-webbrowser-control-content-to-html#2976716) I have a very nice solution. It is necessary to Imports System.IO and Imports System.Text. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub BtHTML_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtHTML.Click
    Dim htmlFile As String = "C:\users\name\fileName"
    File.WriteAllText(htmlFile, WebBrowser1.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml, Encoding.GetEncoding(WebBrowser1.Document.Encoding)) 
End Sub
```